# Kendo Grid Create, Update, Destroy Not Calling WebMethods

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, kendo-grid, webmethod

When I create, edit, or delete a record it looks as if it has done it in the grid but it never calls the associated WebMethod.

I am using the following in my dataSource:

```
        transport: {
            read: {
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "DepartmentHome.aspx/GetMembers",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            create: {
                url: "DepartmentHome.aspx/CreateMember",
                type: "POST"
            },
            update: {
                url: "DepartmentHome.aspx/EditMember",
                type: "POST"
            },
            destroy: {
                url: "DepartmentHome.aspx/DeleteMember",
                type: "POST"
            }                
        },
```

and in my code behind I have defined the WebMethods as such:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void CreateMember()
    {
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\testing.txt", "This is a create.");
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static void EditMember()
    {
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\testing.txt", "This is an update.");
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static void DeleteMember()
    {
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\testing.txt", "This is a delete.");
    }
```

I do see in firebug that it sends:
POST CreateMember
POST EditMember
POST DeleteMember

When I click on the associated buttons the POST data contains the parameters for that row:
FirstName: John
Id: 1
LastName: Smith

However, it never actually calls any of my WebMethods.

The Response back from the POST is just all the html from the page DepartmentHome.aspx.

I am using a WebMethod for read and that is working perfectly.  I don't know what the difference would be?

You can find my complete source code aspx and aspx.cs file here:
http://www.kendoui.com/clientsfiles/3028826e-9aae-631b-85d4-ff000054ddc5_grid.zip?sfvrsn=0

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [following](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net/blob/master/grid-page-methods-crud/Default.aspx.cs) example on GitHub to see a working DataSource with ASP.NET page methods.